# Bootstrap 3 adding correct column class within a row using media query? I am using SASS

Tags: sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been at this for hours and have tried numerous Google searches but have not come to a solid solution. I am working on a website responsive layout(width 940px) using BootStrap 3 and SASS. I have been following BootStrap 3 online documentation which is very helpful. All is working well on desktop, however I am quite curious and would like to know if it is possible to manipulate the mobile layout using media query. Currently, I have two rows within container, and within the each row there are four columns horizontally (Please see the image)

[image]

When I view this very layout on iPhone 5 in "Portrait" view I see all the columns vertically stack as they should be which is good. (Please see the image)

[image]

**ISSUE**

When I view this layout in "Landscape" on iPhone 5, all the columns with two rows remain as the "Portrait View" but stretched out across the screen where as I would would like to see "Portrait View" showing two columns together instead on just one stretched out across the screen. (Please see the image)

[image]

I have tried numerous approaches and followed BootStrap 3 online documentation but have not been able to display two columns on iPhone 5 (Landscape View). Yes, table views are working well....no issues there.

I would highly appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction, please.

I have been following this Bootstrap 3 online resource:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

I am including just one row within this code. I have a "splash-wrapper" this extends three classes, and then "splash-box" within "splash-wrapper"

Here is my code CSS:

```
    .splash-wrapper {   

        // XS
        @extend .col-xs-6;

        // SM
        @extend .col-sm-4;

        // MD
        @extend .col-md-3;

    }       

    .splash-box {

        //DROP SHADOW
        @extend .drop-shadow;

        //BORDER RADIUS
        @extend .border-radius;


        background-color:#ffffff;
        padding:.5em;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<!--    CONTAINER       -->
    <div class="container">
        <!--    ROW     -->
        <div class="row"
            <!--    SPLASH-WRAPPER  --> 
            <div class="splash-wrap">
                <!--    SPLASH BOX      -->
                <div class="splash-box">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
                    readable content of a page when looking at its layout.It is a long established 
                    fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page 
                    when looking at its layout.</p>
                </div><!--  //SPLASH BOX    -->
            </div><!--  //SPLASH-WRAP   -->         

            <div class="splash-wrap">
                <div class="splash-box">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
                    readable content of a page when looking at its layout.It is a long established 
                    fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page 
                    when looking at its layout.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!--  //SPLASH-WRAP   -->         


            <div class="splash-wrap">
                <div class="splash-box">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
                    readable content of a page when looking at its layout.It is a long established 
                    fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page 
                    when looking at its layout.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!--  //SPLASH-WRAP   -->         


            <div class="splash-wrap">
                <div class="splash-box">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
                    readable content of a page when looking at its layout.It is a long established 
                    fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page 
                    when looking at its layout.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!--  //SPLASH-WRAP   -->         

        <!--    //ROW       -->     
    <!--        //CONTAINER     -->
```

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203 - LESS, you'll have to convert to SASS and then change the ems that I use in my media queries to pixels. Read the @mdo comments because this mid-way point between portrait and landscape is not supported by the responsive utilities and some form css will need to be adjusted.

Comment: Cab, thank you so much, I had stumbled upon that discussion and after reading 'mdo' replies, I concluded that 'mdo' just wasn't accepting that there is a gap/issue which needed to be addressed. I m thinking about trying out andyl's solution/hack to see if that makes things better. Have you tried andyl's gist? Thx

Comment: I am using it without any problems at all. I love it.

Comment: He's accepted it but the versioning of Bootstrap requires that it be implemented in version 4 not 3

Comment: This mid way point is isolated by the media queries so removing it has no affect on the other column classes, provided you convert my ems to pixels (I use 16px base)

Comment: I am just getting to know Boot 3 and here comes Boot 4...lol. Are you using BootStrap 4 RC? I am not even sure if there is BS4 RC available? Thx

Comment: No. They are on 3.1.0 and it's not ready yet.

Comment: @cab, It all seems very straight forward but am unable to get it going. I have saved "bootstrap_ms.css.scss" within the "lib" folder and imported it within the "boostrap.scss" file. All compile wells, but am unable to put any of the newly added "col-ms-x" to use or just don't know how to get it going. Would it be possible for me to get some sample to get this going, please. Thank you.

Comment: The best I can do is show you my compiled CSS and an example. My css is in ems and percentages, but you'll get the idea. These are part of the grid.less in my configuration, but others have just been adding the CSS after the bootstrap.css http://jsbin.com/UTiTofoS/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you're someone who wants to not only solve problems in the best way, but prevent future problems, I would look at investing time in learning something like the Susy library for Compass. It's quite confusing at first, but it's designed around the concept of making responsive layouts, so once you get past the learning curve it's rather mind-blowing.

I use this library to create single-page responsive sites within 1-2 days. Check it out:

http://susy.oddbird.net/

Great tutorial:
http://www.zell-weekeat.com/a-complete-tutorial-to-susy/

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve. I am up for all the good knowledge. I appreciate the links. Have you been able to solve such issues as mine using Susy? And wot is Susy's learning curve on the scale of 1 to 10 for the experience developers, please?

Comment: Hey Steve, I did some research on Susy and when I saw Eric Meyer's name, I lost the drive. Don't get me wrong, some of Eric's earlier work was very good. But in recent years, his work has been hit or miss. The other front-end ex evangelist that I avoid is Greg Rewis "The Pompous JackAss".